# detect os version of remote machine

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, operating-system, ip

i'm working on some simple network management tool and it has a scanner that should display all active devices on the network and also show their os and its version.

at least i want to get windows and linux versions, but some other (like cisco ios) are also valuable.

i've looked into tcp/ip fingerprinting using ttl and window size, but it seems not very reliable and only detects whether it is windows of linux.

is it even possible?

p.s. i don't want to use some ready solutions like wmi or snmp

Comment: Cisco IOS is _not_ a Linux-based OS. It existed long before Linux.

Comment: @RonMaupin ok, thank you for your tip